# R: How to list column names vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: r

When I use the following code below in R, it lists the column names horizontally:

```
> colnames(data)
[1] "First"   "Last"   "City"   "Zip"  etc...
```

I wanted to know if I could have the results return vertically, like so:

```
 [1] "first"
 [2] "Last"
 [3] "City"
 [4] "Zip"
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: May I suggest creating your arrays horizontally? That is an array of arrays (columns and rows) and let the first index in the arrays  be the column title? I don't know R but I'm pretty certain that, or something very similar, is possible.

Comment: Side note that the `glimpse` function within the `dplyr` package can be handy for showing data in a similar way.

Comment: `?matrix` maybe - `matrix(colnames(iris))` for instance?

Comment: Thank you, I like the matrix one as well!

Comment: or maybe `t(t(names(iris)))`? I often use it with `sort`: `t(t(sort(names(iris))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a printing issue, we can use `cat`

```
v1 <- c("First", "Last", "City", "Zip" )
cat(v1, sep="\n")
```

Or as commented by @ZheyuanLi

```
cat(paste(paste(v1, collapse= "\n "), "\n"))
```

Comment: Is there a way to list it vertically without having to type all the column headers (e.g. if I had 25 column headers)?  Thank you

Comment: @user1558832  I was creating a reproducible example.  In your case, it would be as ZheyuanLi commented i.e. in place of 'v1', it would be `colnames(data)`

Answer (score 1):

To get an index, as in the request, you could do something like this:

```
v1 <- c("First", "Last", "City", "Zip" )
as.data.frame(v1)
```

This gives:

```
      v1
1  First
2   Last
3   City
4    Zip
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#Method1 (for each column name in one line, along with index number)
as.data.frame(colnames(df))

#Method 2 (for each column name in one line, and no index number)
cat(colnames(df),sep="\n")
```